# Java agent cannot find target class

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven-2

I am attempting to add instrumentation to my Java application. I have successfully created agent code that I attach to my application via the "static" technique (e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/java-instrumentation). When I launch the application, the agent `premain` method is called and then the application executes. Unfortuanetly, `premain` is unable to find the target application class.

My application uses Spring Boot. I am suspecting that this may have something to do with the agent's inability to find the target class, but do not know.

I am not sure what I should provide as far as code, configuration, etc., to illustrate the state of the application. Please let me know what I should include to help.

Here is the exception that occurs when the agent attempts to find and transform the target class:

```
[INFO ] 2023-09-11 14:33:11.900 [main] com.beastcode.devops.prometheus.InstrumentationAgent.premain(InstrumentationAgent.java:28) - [Agent] In premain method
[INFO ] 2023-09-11 14:33:11.903 [main] com.beastcode.devops.prometheus.InstrumentationAgent.premain(InstrumentationAgent.java:29) - [Agent] args: com.beastcode.devops.prometheus.MetricsCollector:collect
[INFO ] 2023-09-11 14:33:11.904 [main] com.beastcode.devops.prometheus.Transformer.transform(Transformer.java:48) - [Agent] Transforming class com/beastcode/devops/prometheus/MetricsCollector
[ERROR] 2023-09-11 14:33:11.908 [main] com.beastcode.devops.prometheus.Transformer.transform(Transformer.java:77) - Exception
javassist.NotFoundException: com.beastcode.devops.prometheus.MetricsCollector
    at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:436) ~[agent-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.beastcode.devops.prometheus.Transformer.transform(Transformer.java:57) ~[agent-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:246) ~[?:?]
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188) ~[?:?]
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:563) ~[?:?]
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:167) ~[?:?]
    at com.beastcode.devops.prometheus.InstrumentationAgent.transform(InstrumentationAgent.java:82) ~[agent-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.beastcode.devops.prometheus.InstrumentationAgent.transformClass(InstrumentationAgent.java:57) ~[agent-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.beastcode.devops.prometheus.InstrumentationAgent.premain(InstrumentationAgent.java:35) ~[agent-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:513) ~[?:?]
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525) ~[?:?]
...
```

`com.beastcode.devops.prometheus.MetricsCollector` is the target class and it certainly exists as this is the "main" application code that is started by Spring Boot. This can be seen later in the console log:

```
...
[INFO ] 2023-09-11 14:33:14.508 [main] com.beastcode.devops.prometheus.MetricsCollector.collectInstantHits(MetricsCollector.java:58) - Metrics information collected
[INFO ] 2023-09-11 14:33:14.508 [main] com.beastcode.devops.prometheus.MetricsCollector.collectInstantHits(MetricsCollector.java:59) - Querying and writing data ...
[INFO ] 2023-09-11 14:33:20.847 [main] com.beastcode.devops.prometheus.MetricsCollector.collectInstantHits(MetricsCollector.java:80) - Done
```

My pom.xml file uses the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to handle building and packaging the application. I'm wondering if the class is not visible because perhaps I'm missing an option.

Here is the application pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.11</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  
  <groupId>com.beast-code.devops</groupId>
  <artifactId>prometheus-metrics-sampler</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
  
  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    
    <slf4j.version>1.7.36</slf4j.version>
    <log4j2.version>2.19.0</log4j2.version>
    
    <prometheus-common.version>1.2.2</prometheus-common.version>

    <gitlab-url>https://gitlab.phactory.beast-code.com</gitlab-url>
    <gitlab-project-id>863</gitlab-project-id>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <name>Spring Milestones</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    
    <repository>
      <id>spring-snapshots</id>
      <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>

    <repository>
      <id>phactory-gitlab-maven</id>
      <url>${gitlab-url}/api/v4/projects/${gitlab-project-id}/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <name>Spring Milestones</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>spring-snapshots</id>
      <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.beast-code.devops</groupId>
        <artifactId>prometheus-common</artifactId>
        <version>${prometheus-common.version}</version>
      </dependency>

    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.beast-code.devops</groupId>
      <artifactId>prometheus-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Here is the agent class:

```
package com.beastcode.devops.prometheus;

import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class InstrumentationAgent {

  private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InstrumentationAgent.class);

  public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    logger.info("[Agent] In premain method");
    logger.info("[Agent] args: {}", agentArgs);

    String[] args = agentArgs.split(":");
    String className = args[0];
    String methodName = args[1];

    transformClass(className, methodName, instrumentation);
  }

  public static void agentmain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    logger.info("[Agent] In agentmain method");
    logger.info("[Agent] args: {}", agentArgs);

    String[] args = agentArgs.split(":");
    String className = args[0];
    String methodName = args[1];

    transformClass(className, methodName, instrumentation);
  }

  private static void transformClass(String className, String methodName, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    Class<?> targetCls = null;
    ClassLoader targetClassLoader = null;

    // See if we can get the class using forName.
    try {
      targetCls = Class.forName(className);
      targetClassLoader = targetCls.getClassLoader();
      transform(targetCls, targetClassLoader, methodName, instrumentation);
      return;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("Class [{}] not found with Class.forName");
    }

    // Otherwise, iterate all loaded classes and find what we want.
    for (Class<?> clazz : instrumentation.getAllLoadedClasses()) {
      if (clazz.getName().equals(className)) {
        targetCls = clazz;
        targetClassLoader = targetCls.getClassLoader();
        transform(targetCls, targetClassLoader, methodName, instrumentation);
        return;
      }
    }

    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to find class [" + className + "]");
  }

  private static void transform(Class<?> clazz, ClassLoader classLoader, String methodName,
      Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    Transformer transformer = new Transformer(clazz.getName(), classLoader, methodName);
    instrumentation.addTransformer(transformer, true);

    try {
      instrumentation.retransformClasses(clazz);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Transform failed for class: [" + clazz.getName() + "]", e);
    }
  }

}
```

Here is the transformer class:

```
package com.beastcode.devops.prometheus;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javassist.CannotCompileException;
import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.CtMethod;
import javassist.NotFoundException;

public class Transformer implements ClassFileTransformer {

  private static Logger     logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Transformer.class);

  // The internal form class name of the class to transform.
  private final String      targetClassName;
  // The class loader of the class we want to transform.
  private final ClassLoader targetClassLoader;

  private final String      methodName;

  public Transformer(String targetClassName, ClassLoader targetClassLoader, String methodName) {
    this.targetClassName = targetClassName;
    this.targetClassLoader = targetClassLoader;
    this.methodName = methodName;
  }

  @Override
  public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
      ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
    byte[] byteCode = classfileBuffer;

    // Replace slashes (/) in target class name with periods (.) to construct a
    // proper Java class name.
    String finalTargetClassName = this.targetClassName.replaceAll("\\.", "/");

    if (!className.equals(finalTargetClassName)) {
      return byteCode;
    }

    if (className.equals(finalTargetClassName) && loader.equals(targetClassLoader)) {
      logger.info("[Agent] Transforming class " + finalTargetClassName);

      /*
       * TODO This is logic specific to what you are trying to instrument into the
       * class and method of interest.
       */

      try {
        ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
        CtClass cc = cp.get(targetClassName);
        CtMethod mtd = cc.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);

        mtd.addLocalVariable("startTime", CtClass.longType);
        mtd.insertBefore("startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();");

        StringBuilder endBlock = new StringBuilder();

        mtd.addLocalVariable("endTime", CtClass.longType);
        mtd.addLocalVariable("opTime", CtClass.longType);
        endBlock.append("endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();");
        endBlock.append("opTime = (endTime-startTime)/1000;");

        endBlock.append("logger.info(\"[Application] Operation completed in:\" + opTime + \" seconds!\");");

        mtd.insertAfter(endBlock.toString());

        byteCode = cc.toBytecode();
        cc.detach();
      } catch (NotFoundException | CannotCompileException | IOException e) {
        logger.error("Exception", e);
      }
    }

    return byteCode;
  }

}
```